# In sharepoint 2010 SPGridview look like asp grid view .Its not showing the filter,sort option

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, menu, spgridview

In sharepoint 2010 SPGridview look like asp grid view .Its not showing the filter,sort option.totally it looking like table.how to make spgridview like the list view in sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want spgridview to work like a list view in sharepoint or do you want to simply have the sort and filter toolbar? Two different things. the list view also enables you do to things like the new item. If so I would encourage you to use the ListViewWebPart instead.(or the new xsltlistviewwebpart)